# What is the actual capacity of a mapped OneDrive?

Tags: network-shares, onedrive

My new HP Stream 14 has a 32GB eMMC drive as the system drive. However, I have a 1TB allowance on OneDrive because I have Office 365. I obviously can't synchronise my OneDrive files because my system drive isn't big enough, so I plan to map OneDrive as a network drive.

I can see from [Microsoft's KB2386902](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2386902) that WebDav mapped drive (including OneDrive) reports incorrect drive capacity:

> #### Cause:
>
> ...WebDAV protocol doesn't support querying server’s disk capacity. With this constrain of WebDAV protocol, Windows client sets
> WebDAV mapping drive's capacity the same as its System Drive.
>
> #### Resolution:
>
> This is by design. A WebDAV mapped drive's capacity is set to match the client machine's System drive capacity. This means
> that the capacity you get from a WebDAV mapped drive is the same as
> your local System drive. System drive is where Windows is installed.
>
> Example:
>
> On a Windows client:
>
> System drive C:\
>
> Free disk space: 39.9 GB
> Used Disk Space: 11.2 GB
>
> WebDAV mapped drive Y:\
>
> Free disk space: 39.9 GB
> Used Disk Space: 11.2 GB

Therefore my OneDrive will map as a 32GB drive rather than the true 1TB.

Will I be limited to 32GB or am I able to use OneDrive as a full 1TB network drive? If I'm restricted to 32GB, then OneDrive is effectively useless for this machine. I really hope that isn't the case.

Comment: The capacity is based on your account.

Answer (score 1):

AS per above, the only way to use the 1TB space is to upload the files to the OD via the Web.

If you have a 2019 Server (windows 10 latest i think) you can utilise Files on Demand (FOD) so you will "SEE" all the files in your OD and you can download whatever you like BUT only to the space available on the Local systems HDD.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the webdav drive is in fact limited to the size of your system drive. So you will not be able add more than 32GB to the entire 1TB of data locally through that drive.

You will though be able to upload up to 1TB of data through the OneDrive website in your browser, so you'll be able to use the full capacity that way.

A good test would be to see what is in fact available through the webdav folder once you go over the 32GB capacity. It's possible that even though the drive reports only 32GB of capacity that you will be able to access the files anyways, but you'll have to test that out.

Answer (score -1):

OneDrive client has the restrictions of your harddrive, but when mapping a driveletter, those restrictions do not apply.

You can store files normally and access them in the same fashion. The only thing you cannot do is make them available offline as that could obviously exceed your diskspace.

Keep in mind that using this is slower as each file access goes over the internet.